# Sails.JS winston always showing in JSON?

Tags: sails.js

I'm using Sails.JS for my web app and my log.js has the following:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const winstonRotate = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const path = require('path');

module.exports.log = {
  level: 'silly',
  colors: false,
  custom: winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)({
        level: 'info',
        colorize: false,
        json: false
      }),
      new (winstonRotate)({
        filename: path.join(process.cwd(), "logs", "main"),
        datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
        zippedArchive: true,
        maxSize: '20m',
        maxFiles: '14d',
        colorize: false,
        'json': false,
      })
    ]
  })
};
```

The problem I have is that I clearly set no JSON and no colors but the console and the file still have them. What am I doing wrong? I've already checked these resources for this issue without success:

https://medium.com/@danielyewright/using-winston-for-logging-in-sailsjs-f9056d72e5e7

https://gist.github.com/barretts/ae7fff301168ef623611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to change `format` on the original post. I have it below:

```
module.exports.log = {
  level: 'silly',
  colors: false,
  custom: winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.printf(info => {
      return `${new Date().toISOString()}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
    }),
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.Console)({
        level: 'verbose',
        colorize: false,
        json: false
      }),
      new (winstonRotate)({
        filename: path.join(process.cwd(), "logs", "main"),
        datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
        zippedArchive: true,
        maxSize: '20m',
        maxFiles: '14d',
        colorize: false,
        json: false,
      })
    ]
  })
};
```